# Deciphering EBNF from XML specification

Tags: ebnf

Take a look at the definition below. What exactly is this supposed to define? According to the EBNF [specification](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-14977.pdf), brackets `[]` define an optional item, so why is the `*` required? Isn't that superfluous (since it means a repetition of zero or more times)?

The second thing is, how do you interpret the part within parentheses? The `-` is the exclusion indicator, so does it mean excluding any of the items within parentheses, or the sequence of all three (zero or more from `^<&`, followed by `]]>`, followed by zero or more from `^<&`)?

```
CharData ::= [^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)
```

Or am I completely mistaken, and this is something other than EBNF?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML specification does not strictly use EBNF as specified by ISO.  If you look at [Section 6](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation) of the XML specification, it defines the notation used.  Square brackets are used in a regex-like manner, not to denote an optional element of the grammar; and the `-` used for exclusion excludes the group within the parentheses as a whole.  Thus, the line you quoted denotes builds up as follows:

- `[^<&]` - any character that is *not* a left angle bracket (`<`) or an ampersand (`&`)
- `[^<&]*` - zero or more characters that are not left angle brackets or ampersands
- `[^<&]* - ([^<&]* ']]>' [^<&]*)` - zero or more characters that are not left angle brackets or ampersands and which do not contain the particular sequence of characters `]]>` anywhere within the overall sequence

Comment: I missed the obvious! They already defined the syntax. The `]]>` refers to the CDATA terminator, so that makes so much more sense than my (mistaken) interpretation. Thanks so much!